# Multiple elements in simple_dom_parser

Tags: php, web-scraping

So I am scraping a webpage, using the html_simple_dom library. There are h5 elements which hold the title to over 50 items I am trying to get. They are not held in one class, as each title has the same class but is closed for each item. So the only option is to loop through the h5 elements or that class element.

The problem is html_simple_dom will only give the first title and that is all. I tried to create a array and loop through them and was given this error.  **Cannot use object of type simple_html_dom_node as array**

I have no clue how to solve this.

```
 <?php

 include("simple_html_dom.php");

 $html=file_get_html("https://www.imdb.com/movies-in-theaters/?ref_=nv_tp_inth_1");


 $list = $html->find('h5',0);

 for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($list); $i++){
 echo $list[$i];
 echo "<br>";
}




?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

- You're trying to access `h3` elements, but use the `h5` selector
- You're telling `simple_dom` that you only want the first element by passing `0` as the second parameter to `find`.
- You need to use the `innertext` property of the node in order to access its content.

You should update as follows:

```
foreach( $html->find('h3') as $h3 )
{
    echo $h3->innertext.'<br />';
}
```

Comment: the h3 was a mistake when I was typing. But as in the code you can see I was passing in h5. I thought passing the 0 in the parameter was telling it to start a 0, not only get the first element.

Comment: do you know how to keep crawling though pagination till the end?